# mysql UPDATE code dont work :((

Tags: php, mysql

I have a like button on my site http://zabavajsa.eu/new/ .
When you click on the button, it shoud add +1 like to the database and it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<form method='post'>
<li>
<button class='like' name='like' value='48'>Like</button>
</li>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['like'])) {
$id = $_POST['like'];
require('db.php');
$resultiiik = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM fotka WHERE id='{$id}'");
$p = $resultiiik->fetch_assoc();
$pocet = $p[like];
$pocet = $pocet +1;
$mysql->query("UPDATE fotka SET like='{$pocet}' WHERE id='{$id}'") or die ('This always write to me -.-');
}
?>
```

Comment: If you want see my database, screenshot is here:  https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t35.0-12/10855861_665930706857029_2124625923_o.jpg?oh=8e3d3fe803c5e764bd886365304c6cf4&oe=5486464D&__gda__=1418114269_2f7c78ad5bbfeb7025180105eb41b4be

Comment: `like` is a horrible column name. Are your column types strings (is code implies they are)?  You should use placeholders rather than interpolation with parameterized SQL.  "don't work" is fantastically unhelpful...what does it do?  In this case it is fairly certain it won't work since has plenty of places where it seems broken, but it's not clear which one is tripping you up (and this isn't a "fix my code" forum).

Comment: @Meldiron: oops, your code has a SQL injection vulnerability in it. Make sure your user input is cleaned prior to injecting it into your database query! What database library are you using?

Comment: @Matt: it's easy to get burnt out helping beginners, I got that T-shirt too. But I don't know if it helps to describe someone's code as _horrible_, or that the OP is _fantastically unhelpful_ - burnout may come for you sooner! I've found of late that stepping away from SO is useful if/when it starts to wind me up. (Generally the downvotes do a fine job of explaining what people thought of a question, and they do their job either by forcing effort or locking people out).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, this

```
<button class='like' name='like' value='48'>Like</button>
```

it needs a "type", let's use a "submit" type

```
<button class='like' name='like' value='48' type='submit'>Like</button>
```

then the word `like` is a MySQL reserved word which needs to be wrapped in ticks

```
SET `like`
```

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html**

`LIKE` is used in string comparisons and pattern matching

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html**
- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html**

Therefore it's best to stay away from using reserved words. You could use the word "**likes**" instead and won't require the column to be escaped, or do as above and wrap it in backticks.

You're also not getting MySQL to signal the proper errors with

```
or die ('This always write to me -.-')
```

use

```
or die(mysqli_error($mysql))
```

or

```
 die('There was an error running the query [' . $mysql->error . ']')
```

Which would have triggered something like:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'like

---

Edit: 
As stated in comments, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: @halfer It won't probably won't make a difference. OP received many  downvotes, and the question stands at being deleted by moderators. Oh well, it's been resolved and that's the important thing. *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii-, it will only be deleted if it is closed, and it hasn't got any CV (yet anyway). It's not an ideal question, but there is prior effort and code, so I think it will remain.

Comment: @halfer Time will tell then.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to @Fred -ii- 2 more bugs:

```
$pocet = $p[like];
```

**like** is a constant, but since you never define a constant named 'like' php will just treat it as string and print a notice if they are enabled. You should use `$pocet = $p['like'];` instead of `$pocet = $p[like];`

And: You don't need to fetch the value just to increment and update it. Your Database can do the work for you:

```
UPDATE fotka SET `like`=`like`+1 WHERE id='{$id}'
```